# How long does it take to get an airline ticket refund?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, airlines, refunds

I paid for my first ticket on November 5th - $959.08. Due to an error with my middle name when I reserved the ticket, I was advised to submit a feedback form with a name correction. Also, I was advised to buy a new ticket, so on November 6, I bought a new ticket and paid $999.10.

I am very upset because I had to pay for this ticket twice, and all the answers I get when I call to check the status of my refund is to wait. I purchased my ticket online through the website CheapOair. Should I contact them too to speed up the process?

Comment: Did you cancel the original ticket? Did you get confirmation that it was actually cancelled ?

Comment: I don't understand. You're having problems with a company and you're asking us if you should contact that company? Who else would you contact?

Comment: It might take upto 4 weeks

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Some things are not clear. *Who* told you to buy a new ticket? *When* did they advise you to do so? If you purchased from CheapOAir, any refund is coming from CheapOAir as well; the airline is not really involved.

Answer (score 6):

Contact the company.

If they don't reimburse you, contact your credit card bank, and revoke the incorrect payment; simple tell them the service you bought was not provided, and the provider is not working with you.

Note that middle names are irrelevant on flight tickets, so simply leave them off in the future. If you never cancelled the first ticket, you might need to able to prove that they told you to proceed that way.
Generally, 'cheapo' websites are typically cheap because they have little or unqualified customer support, and leave you alone when there is an issue. I recommend to always buy from the airline directly.